# How do I connect three of these functions without using the constructor delegation method?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Instructor{

private: 
        string first_name; 
        string last_name; 
        string office_number;
public:
    Instructor(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        first_name = a;
        last_name = b;
        office_number = c;
    }       
    
    void setIns(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        first_name = a;
        last_name = b;
        office_number = c;
    }   
    
    void display()
    {   
                cout << "Instructor: " << first_name << " " << last_name << "\n"
             << "Office number: " << office_number << endl; 
    }


};

class Classroom{

    private: 
            string building_number; 
            string room_number;
    
    public:
        Classroom(string a, string b)
        {   
            building_number = a;
            room_number = b;
        }       
                
        void setClass(string a, string b)
        {
            building_number = a;
            room_number = b;
        }
    
        void display()
        {   
                    cout << "Building Number: " << building_number << "\n"
                 << "Room Number: " << room_number << endl;     
        }

};

class CollegeCourse{

    private: 
            Instructor instructor; 
            Classroom classroom; 
            int credits;
    public:
        CollegeCourse(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, int f)
        {   
            Instructor.setIns(a,b,c);
            Classroom.setClass(d,e);
            credits = f;
        }
        
        void display()
            {
            instructor.display();
            classroom.display();
            cout << "Number of credits: " << credits << endl;
        }

};

int main(){

        CollegeCourse course1("Vincent", "Choong", "1123", "DKG31", "066", 4);
        CollegeCourse course2("Agustin", "Ang", "1152", "DKG31", "073", 4);
    
        cout << "Course 1: " << endl;
        course1.display();
        cout << "\nCourse 2: " << endl;
        course2.display();
        return 0;

}
```

I was trying to declare the value for the Instructor instructor with the functions from Instructor. However, the code I tried doesn't work as there are problems with the functions of the Instructor/Classroom inside the CollegeCourse constructor code. Can anyone point out my mistakes and any way to solve the issues other than the constructor delegation?`

Comment: The right way to do it is `CollegeCourse(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, int f) : instructor(a, b, c), classroom(d, e), credits(f) {}` Is there a reason you want to avoid that? (I assume this is what you mean by "constructor delegation".)

Comment: Yeah, that's the right way to do but I'm more on curious like is there any other way to use the function from the other classes because I have included them as an attribute inside my current function so that I can have a better understanding on the code structure and how it works. I will appreciate if you can give me some advice on that, thank you so much.

Comment: If, for reasons unclear, you don't want to initialize them in the constructor initialization list, then you have to give those classes a default constructor (a constructor that can be called with no arguments). E.g. in the definition of `Instructor` class, add `Instructor(){}` or `Instructor() = default;`

Comment: I did add both constructor into both classes, but the following functions inside the public functions of the CollegeCourse still could not work:

`Instructor.setIns(a,b,c);`
`Classroom.setClass(d,e);`

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: It's `instructor` with lowercase `i`

Comment: It finally works, much appreciated!